# Is it better to add an index to a temp-table at creation of temp-table or after it has been populated?

Tags: sql-server

Which way is better/more efficient when adding an index to a temp-table in SQL Server 2016+?

- Create the index right after the temp-table has been created and before it is populated.
- Create the index after the temp-table has been populated.

Is there any performance difference between these two?

Thanks!

Comment: how many rows do you have in your temp table?

Comment: How are you populating the temp table? If you're inserting rows in one operation it shouldn't matter. If you're inserting rows one at a time, such as from a cursor (and avoid doing that if you can), then create the indexes afterwards otherwise you'll be paying an index update penalty on each insert.

Comment: I’m inserting around 100 million rows. And doing them one at a time but not with a cursor, in a while loop. There’s a lot more going on and a reason I have to do it this way that I could go into if needed.  Sounds like after is the way to go, I hadn’t thought about the index update cost.  Thanks much!!